# algorithm of findKey in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to find key via value from object, and I find that **lodash** provide us convenient api `findKey` could help me.

but my question is, how could `findKey` work? is that different from **hash** common key value mapping?

I don't know anything about that, if possible, could you provide me some example to compare?

thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you specifically want lodash's `findKey` implementation, or any implementation that finds a key?

Comment: @kazenorin thanks for your reply, I just want to know the principle and efficiency of `findKey`, comparing with key-value mapping, I'm not sure how does it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash is an open-source library, you can inspect its source to check their implementations of all functions.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js

`findKey` can probably be traced down to line 716's `baseFindKey` function:

```
function baseFindKey(collection, predicate, eachFunc) {
  var result;
  eachFunc(collection, function(value, key, collection) {
    if (predicate(value, key, collection)) {
      result = key;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

What it does is it runs through the collection, and for every member inside the collection, run the predicate check to see if the member matches the predicate.

If it matches, the key would be returned as the result.